# PHP field validation - ( 2 characters followed by 6 numbers ) example: bp125489

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I am developing a registration form with field validation. So, can someone provide me the logic to validate a field of 8 characters ( 2 letters + 6 numeric mandatory).

Example:
Validate values : bp123456

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in JS or PHP? But in both cases you should use regular expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-z]{2}[0-9]{6}$/i')
{
//do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a regular expression.

```
// Result holds either true or false
var patt = /(^[A-Za-z]{2}\d{6}$)/g;
var result = patt.test(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/function.preg-replace.php) function, which uses regular expressions. Those are quite easy to learn, at least for your desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

i think best way is to use regular expressions. 
PHP example:

```
$value = 'bp123456';
$match = preg_match('^([a-zA-Z]{2}[\\d]{6})$',$value);
```

if $match > 0 then its valid